# QGIS 3.4: Why does DEM not appear after 3D configuration?

Tags: qgis-3, 3d-map

I have a problem with the 3D map view of my DEM in QGIS 3.4. When I open the 3D map view, the DEM is there. Then I go to 3D configuration and choose the DEM for elevation. When I click ok, the map canvas goes blank.

Comment: Which minor version of QGIS are you using (3.4.xx)? I am using 3.4.12 and everything works well.

Comment: Add some information. Could you share screenshot with style for this DEM?